# Does xargs max-procs choose different cores?

Tags: bash, multiprocessing, xargs

My question is if `xargs -P NUM_PROCESSES` will simply start `NUM_PROCESSES` without any preference for processor affinity, or if it will attempt to evenly distribute the processes across cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is no. This is what I suspected, since the mechanisms for setting processor affinity are OS-specific (if even supported).

I don't see any special logic for setting processor affinity in the Apple [xargs.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-116/xargs/xargs.c) source code.